# How to detect two identical audio/video files with different volume level?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

I'm working on program that could compare 2 video files and show difference.
I compare audio track of files using SOX and FFMPEG:

1. invert one of the files (sox)
2. merge other file and invert version of first (sox)
3. detect silence (ffmpeg)

But if two file differs only by volume level - all audio track will be detected as non-silent ranges.

**How to understand that 2 files have the same audio track, but with different volume level?**

I tried to change sound level via sox: `sox -v 1.1 input.wav output.wav`
And then compare statistical information (-n stat). 
It works fine. Result of division parameters audio2/audio1:

```
    Samples read 1.00;
    Length (seconds) 1.00;
    Scaled by 1.00;
    Maximum amplitude 1.10;
    Minimum amplitude 1.10;
    Midline amplitude 1.10;
    Mean norm 1.10;
    Mean amplitude 1.00;
    RMS amplitude 1.10;
    Maximum delta 1.10;
    Mean delta 1.10;
    RMS delta 1.10;
    Rough frequency 1.00;
    Volume adjustment 1/1.10;
```

BUT! When I tried ffmpeg to change volume of video: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -af "volume=10dB" output.mp4` (or `volume=volume=0.5`) and than compared sox audio statistic: I can't find any patterns...

```
Samples read    1.00
Length (seconds)    1.00
Scaled by   1.00
Maximum amplitude   0.71
Minimum amplitude   0.64
Midline amplitude   -2401.73
Mean    norm    0.34
Mean    amplitude   0.50
RMS     amplitude   0.36
Maximum delta   0.37
Mean    delta   0.34
RMS     delta   0.36
Rough   frequency   0.99
Volume adjustment   0.71
```

I will be grateful for any ideas and help.

Comment: Perhaps using something like [chromaprint](https://acoustid.org/chromaprint) is worth considering to detect two identical audio streams. [FFmpeg supports it](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#chromaprint-1): needs `--enable-chromaprint`.